# How to log all the system calls made by a program, say chrome, using linux auditing?

Tags: system-calls, audit, linux-audit

*autrace* can log the system calls made by a program by running it. I want to log the system calls of already running programs. It can be done by finding the process id, but is there any other elegant way? Which may be using the chrome executable file as a parameter to log system calls generated by it?

Comment: `strace`? - "trace system calls and signals"

Answer (score 2):

As @Patrick stated in the comments, you can use the command line tool `strace` to produce a dump of the system calls that are made by a program as it runs.

#### Example

Here's an example showing the command `echo hi` being run.

```
$ strace echo "hi"
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "hi"], [/* 94 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xf73000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9996cf2000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=206010, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 206010, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9996cbf000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\34\242\213?\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2108632, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3f8ba00000, 3932768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3f8ba00000
mprotect(0x3f8bbb6000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3f8bdb6000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x3f8bdb6000
mmap(0x3f8bdbc000, 16992, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3f8bdbc000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9996cbe000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9996cbc000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9996cbc740) = 0
mprotect(0x606000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x3f8bdb6000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3f8b820000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9996cbf000, 206010)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xf73000
brk(0xf94000)                           = 0xf94000
brk(0)                                  = 0xf94000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106055264, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106055264, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9990797000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9996cf1000
write(1, "hi\n", 3hi
)                     = 3
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f9996cf1000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can also increase the details that get output by including the option `-s <size>`. I typically will use `-s 2000` to get 2000 characters of output per call. Also I'll include the switch `-o <file>` to get the output to dump into a file. It's much easier to look at this output after the fact.

#### Example

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o strace.log echo "hi" 
hi
```

And here's the file:

```
$ cat strace.log 
execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "hi"], [/* 94 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1061000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78bdab3000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=206010, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 206010, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f78bda80000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\34\242\213?\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\30\" \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\n\0@\0+\0*\0\6\0\0\0\5\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\240\213?\0\0\0@\0\240\213?\0\0\0000\2\0\0\0\0\0\0000\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\360\26\30\0\0\0\0\0\360\26\270\213?\0\0\0\360\26\270\213?\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\34\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\240\213?\0\0\0\0\0\240\213?\0\0\0\344W\33\0\0\0\0\0\344W\33\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\6\0\0\0 g\33\0\0\0\0\0 g\333\213?\0\0\0 g\333\213?\0\0\0\240Q\0\0\0\0\0\0@\233\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\200\233\33\0\0\0\0\0\200\233\333\213?\0\0\0\200\233\333\213?\0\0\0\360\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\360\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0p\2\0\0\0\0\0\0p\2\240\213?\0\0\0p\2\240\213?\0\0\0D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\4\0\0\0 g\33\0\0\0\0\0 g\333\213?\0\0\0 g\333\213?\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\220\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0P\345td\4\0\0\0\f\27\30\0\0\0\0\0\f\27\270\213?\0\0\0\f\27\270\213?\0\0\0\\h\0\0\0\0\0\0\\h\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Q\345td\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\0\0\0\0R\345td\4\0\0\0 g\33\0\0\0\0\0 g\333\213?\0\0\0 g\333\213?\0\0\0\3408\0\0\0\0\0\0\3408\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\206\353)\243\237\22p\240\253\216F\316.Tkn\303R\312\10\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\1\0\0\0GNU\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\6\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\363\3\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\16\0\0\0\0000\20D\240 \2\1\210\3\346\220\305E\214\0\300\0\10\0\5\200\0`\300\200\0\r\212\f\0\4\20\0\210D2\10.@\210P<, \0162H&\204\300\214\4\10\0\2\2\16\241\254\32\4f\300\0\3002\0\300\0P\1 \201\10\204\v  ($\0\4 P\0\20X\200\312DB(\0\6\200\20\30B\0 @\200\0\tP\0Q\212@\20\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\21\20", 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2108632, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3f8ba00000, 3932768, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3f8ba00000
mprotect(0x3f8bbb6000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3f8bdb6000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x3f8bdb6000
mmap(0x3f8bdbc000, 16992, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3f8bdbc000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78bda7f000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78bda7d000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f78bda7d740) = 0
mprotect(0x606000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x3f8bdb6000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3f8b820000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f78bda80000, 206010)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1061000
brk(0x1082000)                          = 0x1082000
brk(0)                                  = 0x1082000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106055264, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106055264, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f78b7558000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f78bdab2000
write(1, "hi\n", 3)                     = 3
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f78bdab2000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can include any program or command that you can typically run in your shell as an argument to `strace`. It's probably the most useful tool included with Linux in terms of gaining insights into how executables work within your system.

I'm only scratching the surface here, you can instruct `strace` to only show system calls or signals too. Check out the `man strace` page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the **question**:

> I want to log the system calls of already running programs.

`strace` can *start* a program by name, but for "already running programs", you must (as in `autrace`) refer to the process-id.

A given executable can have multiple processes associated with it.  You could make a script which checks all of the `exe` links under `/proc`, e.g.,

```
/proc/*/exe
```

to see which match the executable that you're interested in, and (since the intermediate directory name *is* the process id) make `strace` run for each of those processes.

For any process that you *can* trace, the `exe` link is the pathname of an executable.  Your script would read the pathname (using `readlink`) and if it matches, run `strace` with the `-p` option for the corresponding process id.  Of course, you would run those in the background, to be able to handle multiple processes.

Collecting those together into a coherent logfile might (or might not) be what you want to do next.  Your script could pipe the results from `strace` to `logger`, making the result one big logfile.

Further reading:

- [proc - process information pseudo-filesystem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), explains *`/proc/[pid]/exe`*
- [Bash Shell Script - Write to Custom Log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045946/bash-shell-script-write-to-custom-log-file)
- [Shell scripting: Write message to a syslog / log file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html)

as well as the manual pages:

- [**`autrace`** - a program similar to strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/autrace.8.html)
- [**`strace`** - trace system calls and signals](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)